# Rename external drive Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, gparted, disk, external-hdd

Feel like I'm probably missing something obvious, but looking to rename an external HDD on Ubuntu 22.04.

I open Disk, select the drive in question, click on the Settings dialog, and then 'Edit Filesystem', where I'm presented with a 'Change Filesystem Label' prompt (with previous name entered as 'Label'.  I change to desired name, hit 'Change' and am prompted with the following.  I've tried unmounting before changing with the same results.  Any ideas. [image]

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for chris: 
Model: Seagate One Touch HDD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 5001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB   210MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      211MB   5001GB  5001GB                                     msftdata


Model: Seagate BUP SL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 5001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   5001GB  5001GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, hidden, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   257GB  257GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      257GB   322GB  64.4GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      322GB   511GB  190GB   ext4
 5      511GB   512GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: extfatlabel? You have a 5TB drive with exFAT? Not recommended if that is the case. And is it partitioned or just the entire drive formatted? Post this: `sudo parted -l` in question above.

Comment: @oldfred, is that suboptimal?  just formatted to my knowledge.  updated the question.

Comment: It looks like sdc2 is NTFS data which is ok if using with Windows. But this is an Ubuntu question & answer site. Do you not have a format on sdb2? NTFS not the best for Ubuntu backup as it loses ownership & permissions since not supported in Microsoft formats.

Comment: @oldfred, that's right.  It's a mixed use HDD used by both linux and windows.  New HDD will serve the same purpose.  Do you expect formatting to NTFS will resolve the issue?

Comment: I would think both Ubuntu & Windows would need to see it as NTFS. You must keep Windows fast start up  off as it sets hibernation flag preventing read/write from Linux. And Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. With gpt, there are two labels, one for partition (partlabel) and one for file system(label). `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint`  I used this on a NTFS partition on NVMe drive. `sudo ntfslabel /dev/nvme0n1p4 shared` And I normally use sgdisk for partlabel, if I forget in gparted when creating partition. The gnome Disks app also can be used.

Comment: Same issue with a WD called My Book. The out of the box formatting is exfat and left it like that, because the quick button to format did not do anything.

Comment: @DaReal, was able to get around this by booting into windows and changing there.  Also formatted to NTFS, as the other was, if it's not broken...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply after you solved it already anyway! I ended up formatting the entire disk in Ubuntu via Files -> right click on My Book -> Properties -> Open in Disks. There it allowed me to rename while formatting. Did mean I had to copy over all the data to another place first :/